# Android S/mime opensource mail client

Tags: android, open-source, cryptography, smime

I'm wondering if any one knows any open-source mail client or plug-ins for it to handle SMIME mails.

Something like DJIGZO for android but , OPEN SOURCE!
Cause my encrypted mails are not standard and I need to do some modification on it.

Comment: you can extract the jar files which you are using for that and can change it right ??

Comment: @Rajesh can you be more specific? Which jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look on this . and let me know your comments. 
**http://www.example-code.com/android/smtp_sendEncryptedCer.asp**

Comment: Yep I know the chilkat, it's the good one but not free :(